# How to apply mapcar to a function with multiple arguments

Tags: mapping

I have `packages` variables that have list of github users and package names.

```
(defvar packages '('("auto-complete" . "auto-complete")
                   ("defunkt" . "markdown-mode")))
```

I want to `git clone` if the file is not exist yet.

```
(defun git-clone (author name)
  (let* ((repo-url (concat "git@github.com:" author "/" name ".git")))
    (print repo-url)
    (unless (file-exists-p (concat "~/.emacs.d/git/" name))
      (shell-command (concat "git clone " repo-url " ~/.emacs.d/git/" name)))))
```

And I want to apply `git-clone` to all packages variable to `packages` list. But I could not figure out how to apply with arguments.

```
; This obviously doesn't work
(mapcar `git-clone `packages)
```

Comment: By the way, you have an extra `'` in your `defvar` declaration.

Comment: FWIW, this has got to be a duplicate, but I don't have time to search for it. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an anonymous lambda function to take each element of your list and apply your function to it.

Example:

```
(defvar packages '(("auto-complete" . "auto-complete")
                   ("defunkt" . "markdown-mode")))

(defun toy-fnx (author name)
  "Just testing."
  (message "Package %s by author %s" name author)
  (sit-for 1))

(mapcar (lambda (package)
          (funcall #'toy-fnx (car package) (cdr package)))
        packages)
```

Note that, if you don't care about the return values (ie, your function is only for side effects, which appears to be the case here), you can use `mapc` in place of `mapcar`:

```
(mapc (lambda (package)
        (funcall #'toy-fnx (car package) (cdr package)))
      packages)
```

For your specific purposes, a loop may be simplest:

```
(cl-dolist (package packages)      ; or dolist if you don't want to use cl-lib
  (funcall #'toy-fnx (car package) (cdr package)))
```

Comment: There's no advantage to `cl-dolist` over plain `dolist` here.

Comment: @npostavs: edited.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about `funcall`.

Comment: Hmm, I skipped over the `funcall` before, but looking again it seems redundant, why not just call `toy-fnx` directly?

Comment: @npostavs: correct. It was just a way to illustrate mapcar and friends.

Answer (score 9):

If you're happy using [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) you can use `-each` and destructuring `-let`:

```
(require 'dash)

(--each packages
  (-let [(author . name) it]
    (git-clone author name)))
```

Alternatively, you can use `-lambda` from dash.el to create an anonymous function with destructuring:

```
(mapcar
 (-lambda ((author . name)) (git-clone author name))
 packages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the [answer by Dan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18833/26669), if you do this kind of thing often it may be useful to define a 'starred' variant of `mapcar`, as one does in e.g. Python:

```
(defun my-mapcar* (func arglist)
  (mapcar 
     (lambda (args)
       (apply func args))
     arglist))
```

so that e.g.

```
(my-mapcar* #'+ '((1) (1 1) (1 1 1) (1 1 1 1))
      ⇒ (1 2 3 4)
```